# How to boot from a backup bios chip?

Tags: spi

Is it possible to boot a pc with a second BIOS on a spi chip which is connected to the one soldered to the motherboard?
Of course the right pins would have to be connected but I'm unsure about CS and Hold.
Some mainboards from gigabyte already have a second bios but I don't know how this works under the hood, some others have a special header where you can attach a programmer or SPI chip like:

http://pcengines.ch/spi1a.htm
or 
https://www.thelabeshop.com/files/5/3106/Universal_SPI_Pin_Header.pdf

So this already goes in the right direction.

The ideal case for me would be to just connect a SOIC8 clip to the onboard chip and the pins on the other end from the clip to the ones from the backup chip. The onboard BIOS should just be ignored during boot. However, I don't know if this would work or if other parts are required.
Is this somehow dependent on the software on the chip? If I delete all data from the onboard chip would the second chip automatically be selected or is there more low level stuff going on on the chips which prevents this?

Comment: Unless the BIOS has a dual boot loader built-in, you are wasting your time.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? From what I understand this should be independent on the BIOS since the BIOS gets loaded _after_ one of the chips has been selected.

Comment: if you are able to delete the data from the onboard chip, then why would you not be able to load the second chip image into the onboard chip?

Comment: maybe the mobo already has a second bios chip.  is there a "recovery" jumper of some kind onboard?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the motherboard supports an auxiliary BIOS chip, you will need to perform surgery on the motherboard PCB. SPI requires a separate chip select for each slave device.

Without explicit support, you need, at a minimum, to disconnect the CS pin from the on-board device. This might mean lifting the pin of the IC or cutting the trace (which might be buried in an inside layer of the PCB).

If you need this, I’d highly suggest buying a mobo with explicit support.

Comment: I'd like to keep the chip on the mobo in its original state, so no desoldering or cutting traces. But there might be no way around it. However, the links posted above indicate that it is possible. But I don't know if this related to how the mainboard PCB is designed, i.e. with support for a second SPI chip. Or there has to be some kind of switch on these boards which allows to boot from one of the chips. The CS pin is definitly connected to the PCB but maybe the SPI header allows switching. Since my knowledge of electronic circuits is rather limited, the header function is above my head though